# create edit text only accept or able to enter only alphabetical character from a-z only android

Tags: android

i want to make a edit text in which can only be able to enter  only alphabatical character means from a-z no other numeric or special charaacter are not allowed so how to do it?

i had tried

```
<EditText
     **android:inputType="text"**
     android:id="@+id/state" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dip" 
     android:layout_height="40dip"
      android:layout_width="200dip"
        />
```

but it accept all the values means numeric and special character also.so how to restrict it
means user can only enter a-z values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the InputType  in android  this is the reference [Input Type API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

Comment: said do it and do it inside textChangedListener()..:)

Comment: @parag hi i did it pls. accept my question ..so that i can post my answer ,below 100 reputations i cant post my answer... vv thanks...

Answer (score 3):

Type in  your xml respective EditText....

**android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"**

EditText will not accept digits or special character but alphabets only..

Answer (score 2):

i did it using

```
                            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                    int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                  for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                      if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))) { 
                              return ""; 
                      } 
              }                     return null;
            } 
    }; 


        EditText etcity=   ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.city));
        etcity.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want EditTest to have only characters with white spaces use this:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
```

Note that white space at the end of `abcd...` string.